# Adding metadata (x-amz-meta-SOMEINFO) while uploading to S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am looking for a way to programmatically insert custom metadata (x-amz-meta-SOMEINFO) while uploading a file into AWS S3.

Currently I am inserting the file using a Python lambda function into S3 bucket using the below command.

> open('/tmp/newFile.docx',
>   'wb').write(attachment.get_payload(decode=True))
>   s3r.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/newFile.docx', outputBucket,
>   attachment.get_filename())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the above issue using 'ExtraArgs'

```
s3r.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/newFile.docx', outputBucket, str(time.time())+'-'+attachment.get_filename(),
    ExtraArgs={"Metadata": {"SOMEINFO": value}})
```

The metadata 'SOMEINFO' gets saved as x-amz-meta-SOMEINFO'.